# Failed to accept license when updating android sdk manager

Tags: android

I am using command line to update android sdk manager as below:

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux24/tools/bin/sdkmanager  --update
```

It will print the license agreement and ask me to type `y/N`. After type `y` I got below error:

```
Accept? (y/N): y
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
done
```

I don't have UI on the system and I have to use command line for all the configurations.

But why is this happened? What wrong with my android environment? Do I need to configure something in order to update sdk?

Comment: I'm also having this issue, were you able to determine which the properties file?

Comment: For me the problem was caused by the tools folder was in /opt, but the sdkmanager need access to write two folders up from tool's folder. So, I left /opt/android/tools and just execute /opt/android/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update. Worked for me

Comment: Running with sudo simply solved the problem for me